# java: illegal start of expression, между двумя массивами Public static void

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intelij

Я так и не понял в чем ошибка. Я и так и сяк.
В фрагменте между этим и public static void выдает "java: illegal start of expression" и "java: ';' expected". Как решить эту проблему??
action.accept(pLayer1);

```
    public void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Player pLayer1 = new Player(1000, 200);
        Player enemy = new Player(10000, 50);
        Consumer<Player> action;
        BiConsumer<Player, Player> action2;

        action = (Hero, my_hero) -> {
            System.out.println(pLayer1.Health);
            System.out.println(pLayer1.Health);
            action2 = (Hero me2, Hero enemy2) -> {
                pLayer1.get_energy() += 700;
            };

            action.accept(pLayer1);
            action2.accept(enemy, pLayer1);
            System.out.println(enemy.Health);
            System.out.println(enemy.energy);
        }
         public static void match(); {
            pLayer1 = new Player(1000, 200);
            enemy = new Player(10000, 50);

            Scanner my_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (pLayer1.Health > 0 && enemy.Health > 0) {
                System.out.print("What action do you want to take? If attack, please press 1, if defend - 2, and if you need energy, press 3. For break press 4");
                int choice = my_scanner.nextInt();
                if (choice == 1) {
                    pLayer1.attack(enemy);
                }
                if (choice == 2) {
                    pLayer1.defend();
                }
                if (choice == 3) {
                    enemy.get_energy();
                }
                Random gen;
                choice = gen.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1; //
                System.out.println("RANDOM = :" + choice);

                if (choice == 1) {
                    enemy.attack(pLayer1);
                }
                if (choice == 2) {
                    enemy.defend();
                }
                if (choice == 3) {
                    enemy.get_energy();
                }
                System.out.println("My health :" + choice);
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Присваивание выражения переменной `action` идёт вне какого-либо метода.

Comment: весь этот фрагмент кода - сплошная проблема. что вы хотели написать? что должен делать этот код?

Comment: Метод `public static void match()`        1) Описан внутри метода `main`. Уберите одну закрывающую скобку после него и поставьте перед ним;        2) Точка с запятой после заголовка метода, перед его телом: `public static void match(); {`      Но это только что касается синтаксиса, на смысл кода я не смотрел.

Comment: А вообще любая IDE умеет подсвечивать парные скобки. Ставьте курсор на закрывающую и увидите соответствующую открывающую,  и наоборот. Проверяйте так свой код время от времени. И изучайте синтаксис, где должны быть точки с запятой, где могут быть, но не обязательно, а где их не должно быть.